# Is it possible to write data to JSON with Extjs4?

Tags: json, extjs, proxy, extjs4, writer

Is it possible to write data to JSON without php/asp, only ExtJS? Can someone provide simple example of how to do this *(sending form data to Json)*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do you want to store your json data exactely ?
Since you don't want to use a server-side script to back it up, I presume it's client-side.

Then I'd say a combination of [Ext.data.writer.Json](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.writer.Json) + one of the following :

- [Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage)
- Ext.data.proxy.Memory
- Ext.data.proxy.SessionStorage

Comment: Thanks, what I ment is to actually write JSON file located on server, but I see that this is not possible without server-side scripting, cheers!

Comment: Hi Davor, Can u plz explain what server-side scripting is required here?